# Custom Sink for Flume-ng null event

Tags: flume

I am trying to write a custom sink for flume-ng. I looked at the existing sinks and documentation and coded it up. However, the 'process()' method that's supposed to receive the events always ends up with null. 
I am doing Event event = channel.take(); but the event is null. I see in the logs that this method is called repeatedly as the event is still in the channel.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the skeleton of a process function ...If you fail getting an event you **rollback**, change the status to **BACKOFF** . If not you **commit** and set status to **READY** . No matter what , you always close the transaction.

```
    Status status = null;
    Channel channel = getChannel();
    Transaction transaction = channel.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();
    try {
        Event event = channel.take();

        if (event != null && validEvent(event.getBody()) >= 0) {
           # make some printing
        }
        transaction.commit();
        status = Status.READY;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        transaction.rollback();
        status = Status.BACKOFF;
        logger.error("Failed to deliver event. Exception follows.", ex);
        throw new EventDeliveryException("Failed to deliver event: " + ex);
    } finally {
        transaction.close();
    }
    return status;
```

I am sure this gonna work :).

Comment: hey i have a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46479157/streaming-kafka-messages-to-mysql-database
do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 4):

This is by design. The sink runner will poll the sink with `null` events so it can be sure the sink is alive and ready to accept future events. When you receive a `null` event, ensure you return `Status.BACKOFF`, and sink processor will wait a bit before trying again.

Comment: Strange that [documentation](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeDeveloperGuide.html#sink) says nothing about that.

Comment: I agree. Flume documentation is very minimal and should be a little more detailed.

Comment: What is the backoff duration? And how is it controlled? The AbstractSink class does not implement methods like the  Sources do e.g.
   public long getBackOffSleepIncrement()
   public long getMaxBackOffSleepInterval(