# Streaming Kafka Messages to MySQL Database

Tags: apache-kafka, flume-ng

I want to write Kafka messages to MySQL database. There is an example in [this](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/11647.streaming-kafka-messages-to-mysql-data) link. In that example, apache flume used for consume messages and writing it to MySQL. I'm using same code and when i run the `flume-ng agent` and `event` always becomes `null`

And my `flume.conf.properties` file is:

```
agent.sources=kafkaSrc
agent.channels=channel1
agent.sinks=jdbcSink

agent.channels.channel1.type=org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel
agent.channels.channel1.brokerList=localhost:9092
agent.channels.channel1.topic=kafkachannel
agent.channels.channel1.zookeeperConnect=localhost:2181
agent.channels.channel1.capacity=10000
agent.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity=1000
agent.channels.channel1.parseAsFlumeEvent=false


agent.sources.kafkaSrc.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
agent.sources.kafkaSrc.channels = channel1
agent.sources.kafkaSrc.zookeeperConnect = localhost:2181
agent.sources.kafkaSrc.topic = kafka-mysql

agent.sinks.jdbcSink.type = com.stratio.ingestion.sink.jdbc.JDBCSink
agent.sinks.jdbcSink.connectionString = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?useSSL=false
agent.sinks.jdbcSink.username=root
agent.sinks.jdbcSink.password=pass
agent.sinks.jdbcSink.batchSize = 10
agent.sinks.jdbcSink.channel =channel1
agent.sinks.jdbcSink.sqlDialect=MYSQL
agent.sinks.jdbcSink.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
agent.sinks.jdbcSink.sql=INSERT INTO kafkamsg(msg) VALUES(${body:varchar})
```

Where I'm wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my referance example, flume listens kafka for `kafka-mysql` topic. But this code works for `kafkachannel` topic. So we need to produce messages to `kafkachannel` topic, i don't know why.